# How to Replace Default icon in Visual Studio 2013 apache cordova application for ipad/iphone

Tags: angularjs, cordova, visual-studio-2013, ionic-framework, apache-cordova

I tried in different ways to replace default app icon but its not working for me.i added custom icons **res/icons/ios** in this path. when I build my cordova app on remote device(ipad) its always showing default app icon.if anyone help me to solve my problem? I also added following lines into my config.xml file.

*

```js
 <platform name="android">
        <!--
            ldpi    : 36x36 px
            mdpi    : 48x48 px
            hdpi    : 72x72 px
            xhdpi   : 96x96 px
            xxhdpi  : 144x144 px
            xxxhdpi : 192x192 px
        -->
        <icon src="res/android/ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
        <icon src="res/android/mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
        <icon src="res/android/hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
        <icon src="res/android/xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
        <icon src="res/android/xxhdpi.png" density="xxhdpi" />
        <icon src="res/android/xxxhdpi.png" density="xxxhdpi" />
    </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
        <!-- iOS 8.0+ -->
        <!-- iPhone 6 Plus  -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-60-3x.png" width="180" height="180" />
        <!-- iOS 7.0+ -->
        <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-60-2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
        <!-- iPad -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-60-2x.png" width="152" height="152" />
   
        <!-- iOS 6.1 -->
        <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-40-2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
        <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon.png" width="60" height="60" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
        <!-- iPad -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
        <!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-small-2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
        <!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-50-2x.png" width="100" height="100" />
    </platform>
```

Comment: Try removing the ios platform using CLI and add ios platform again.

Comment: Which custom icons did you add, but aren't seeing for your app?

Comment: Just i included <icon src = "res/icons/Myicon.png" > in my config file.i tried in different ways still i am not fix it.have any idea share it

Answer (score 0):

You need to open your project in xcode and find the Resources folder -> images.xsassets

http://ticons.fokkezb.nl/

above link is useful for create your icon and splash-screen for your ios application.

once that downloaded you drag and drop icons in appicon and splashscreen in lanchimage

I hope this work for you.

Comment: how to open my apache cordova application in xcode?

Comment: your project folder -> platform -> ios -> <project name>.xscodeproj

Comment: I created cordova app using visual studio 2013.In VS solution explorer will not showing me platforms folder.could you give me a solution now? How to add platforms externally for my cordova app.

Comment: in vs2013 platform folder hide you need to find that folder

Comment: As you said I checked  solution explorer. I click Show all files button  it doesn't show platform folder. Help me to add platforms?

Comment: you need to google about it "how to add ios platform in vs2013 corodva app"